# Can hunchentoot host CGI application?

Tags: hunchentoot

We have a CGI application developed using python, which can be hosted in erlang YAWS easily:

```
>cat ~/yaws.conf
...
<server 192.168.1.2>
    port = 8000
    listen = 0.0.0.0
    docroot = /media/G/www/qachina/
    access_log = false
    appmods = <cgi-bin, yaws_appmod_cgi>
</server>
...
```

Now we want to host the application in a lisp web server.  Maybe hunchentoot can do it ?

Sincerely!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably something to do with EOL characters.

From [Chunga API docs](http://weitz.de/chunga/#read-line%2a), you can see the ***read-line**** function expects a CR as EOL marker, which is not the default for *nixes. The following should make it work (it works for me):

```
(setf chunga:*accept-bogus-eols* t)
```

EDIT: further reading the description of ****accept-bogus-eols**** I can see why this is the normal behavior of Chunga: the library itself conforms to RFC2616 (HTTP 1.1) in which the HTTP protocol's default EOL marker is CRLF.

Comment: BTW, how to call "hunchentoot-cgi::create-cgi-dispatcher-and-handler" for the whole cgi-bin/*.py.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have installed hunchentoot-cgi and tested it. The following is a simple python script file:

```
>cat cgi-bin/nav.py
#!/usr/local/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
print """from Python"""
```

when i visited http://127.0.0.1:8000/cgi-bin/nav.py, hunchentoot reported:

```
11111111111111111
**End of file, but expected #\Newline.**
[2011-12-28 13:35:16 [ERROR]] error in handle-cgi-script from URL /cgi-bin/nav.py
127.0.0.1 - [2011-12-28 13:35:16] "GET /cgi-bin/nav.py HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-"    
"Opera/9.80 (X11; FreeBSD 8.2-RELEASE i386; U; zh-cn) Presto/2.10.229 Version/11.60"
```

By hackiing hunchentoot-cgi.lisp, i found the function "handle-cgi-script" reported the error:

```
 (handler-case
  (with-input-from-program (in path nil env)
  (format t "11111111111111111~%")
  (chunga:with-character-stream-semantics
      (loop for line = (chunga:read-line* in)
       until (equal line "")
       do
         (format t "22222222222222222:~A~%" line)
         (destructuring-bind (key val)
              (ppcre:split ": " line :limit 2)
              (setf (hunchentoot:header-out key) val))
              (format t "22222222222222222~%")))
  (format t "33333333333333333~%")
  (let ((out (flexi-streams:make-flexi-stream
      (tbnl:send-headers)
      :external-format tbnl::+latin-1+)))
      (copy-stream in out 'character))
  (format t "33333333333333333~%"))
  (error (error)
      (format t "~A~%" error)
      (tbnl:log-message* :error "error in handle-cgi-script from URL ~A"
      (tbnl:request-uri*))))
```

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: I have posted the answer already, but I cannot stop thinking why would you run an external "heavy" process like python in CGI mode (meaning it spawns a new python process for every single page hit that uses that CGI service). Wouldn't it be much better to reimplement it in-process, as a Hunchentoot handler?

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. It is an old application and we have no time to modify it now. Maybe it will be implemented as a hunchentoot handler in the future

Comment: Another option is to convert the python CGI to **SCGI** (similar to **FastCGI** but a much simpler protocol). That would give you the advantage to have a long lived python process serving requests to the web server using the CGI protocol. That, of course, requires SCGI support from the web server to forward the corresponding requests to the running python app. But you gain better response times. [SCGI on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Common_Gateway_Interface).

Answer (score 0):

Strange behavior about "merge-pathnames":

```
* (merge-pathnames  "nav.py" "/media/E/myapp/cgi-bin/")
#P"/media/E/myapp/cgi-bin/nav.py"
```

it works normally in SBCL REPL. However, when hacking "create-cgi-dispatcher-and-handler", i add the following lines:

```
(defun create-cgi-dispatcher-and-handler (uri-prefix base-path &optional content-type)
;...
(format t "SName=~A SPath=~A BPath=~A~% the path is ~A~%" script-name script-path base-path (merge-pathnames script-path base-path))
;...
```

Calling it as below:

```
(pushnew (hunchentoot-cgi::create-cgi-dispatcher-and-handler
      "/cgi-bin/"
      (make-pathname :name "cgi-bin/" :type nil :version nil :defaults *this-file*)
      ) *dispatch-table* :test #'equal)
```

Then visiting http://127.0.0.1:8000/cgi-bin/nav.py, it reports:

```
SName=/cgi-bin/nav.py SPath=nav.py BPath=/media/E/myapp/cgi-bin/
the path is /media/E/myapp/nav.py
```

In a short word:

(merge-pathnames "nav.py" "/media/E/myapp/cgi-bin/") returns #P"/media/E/myapp/cgi-bin/nav.py" in REPL.  But it returns "/media/E/myapp/nav.py" in hunchentoot-cgi.lisp.

Sincerely!

Comment: I think you want `(make-pathname :directory '(:absolute "cgi-bin"))`, because **merge-pathnames** will replace the _name_ part of the path.

Comment: "(handle-cgi-script (merge-pathnames script-path base-path) content-type)" is from "hunchentoot-cgi.lisp".  (merge-pathnames "nav.py" "/media/E/myapp/cgi-bin/") is ok in SBCL'REPL but not in "hunchentoot-cgi.lisp".